# Java Jpa @ManyToOne relations missing from JSON results

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I am working on an API using `PagingAndSortingRepository` I am trying to get a list of objects from the repository with their relations attached. This used to work but it stopped suddenly here is my setup;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "products/imported", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<AmazonProduct> importedProducts (...) throws EncoderException, RestClientException {
        ...
        return this.AmazonProductRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Here is my Product class which I try to return via json;

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Entity
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = MyJsonType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "featuresJson", typeClass = productFeaturesJsonType.class),
})
public class AmazonProduct {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "brandId") 
    @JsonManagedReference
    private AmazonBrand brand;

    public AmazonBrand getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(AmazonBrand brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }
}
```

This is the brand relationship;

```
@Entity
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class AmazonBrand {
    ...

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="brand", fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    private List<AmazonProduct> products;


    public List<AmazonProduct> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<AmazonProduct> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

When I run this via the browser I get;

```
[ {
  "publisherId" : null,
  "legalDisclaimer" : null,
  "asin" : "B00KSF9RAG",
  "title" : "Eye Mask / Sleep Mask - Sleeping Masks for...",
  "features" : {
    "features" : [ "...", "...", "..." ]
  }
}]
```

I expect this to come with the property; amazonBrand. It used to work but it does not currently work.

My repository class looks like this;

```
public interface AmazonProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<AmazonProduct, Long> {

}
```

Comment: Try removing the lazy fetch from the AmazonBrand property

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Did you try changing the fetch type to eager?

Comment: Yes, I changed it to `FetchType.EAGER`

Comment: Maybe you could try explicit '@JsonInclude'

Comment: It is ignoring any properties that are not connected to any table field, for example if I add; private ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Hello", "World")); and add the getter and setter. This will not be returned in the json result. But if I add another field `private String greeting = "Hello";` this will be returned in the json result. So it looks like it is only serialising table values.

Comment: Could it be that the property is null, and being discarded?

Comment: I have tried `return product.getBrand();` and I am getting the brand json object fine.

Comment: I didn't think this would be too difficult. It seems like a very easy problem to solve for an experienced developer. I have only started working with Java. I was working with java for a long time I think this would be very easy to solve. I am surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the DB dependencies, you may need to place your annotations on the 'getters' rather than the private fields. I had a similar issue when using Hibernate with MySql.

Comment: I get the error when I change the annotations for the brand property to get getBrand(); `Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table product add constraint FKti0lsgnnoerhclcve20iho3un foreign key (brand) references brand (id)]` I think it it trying to create 2 fields. `@Transient` didn't work either.

Comment: It may have something to do with the `@TypeDefs` and the `@JsonIgnoreProperties`.  Have you tried using Projections?  
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts

Answer (score 0):

Try using @Cacheable(false) on your entity class

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for [JsonBackReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html) says:

> Annotation used to indicate that associated property is part of
>   two-way linkage between fields; and that its role is "child" (or
>   "back") link. Value type of the property must be a bean: it can not be
>   a Collection, Map, Array or enumeration. Linkage is handled such that
>   the property annotated with this annotation is not serialized; and
>   during deserialization, its value is set to instance that has the
>   "managed" (forward) link.

You can see you can't use the collection with `@JsonBackReference`, rather it needs to be a bean.

So, the following line is not working:

```
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy="brand", fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
private List<AmazonProduct> products;
```

I am able to get some entries I remove the annotation on both classes.